# Add jdoc of custom class to enunciate docs?

Tags: javadoc, enunciate

I have a Maven-JAX-RS project written in java and using enunciate to automatically generate docs with every build. So far, it works well - he generates api-docs for all REST-Endpoints in my project.

Now i have written some util-classes with useful jdoc too - but these classes are not Endpoints - so, enunciate will not include them.

Is there any way to tell enunciate, that he should generate additional docs with the jdoc of some additional classes? I thought there should be a way to manually configure that in enunciate.xml, but i can't find a working solution...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing the class as described in [Enunciate: Multi-Module Projects](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ENUNCIATE/Multi-Module+Projects)?

Comment: yes i tried that, did not work - or at least, i could not find the jdoc anywhere of this custom included class in the resulting html :)

Comment: Huh. You may also need to use the api-classes configuration element:

    <api-classes>
      <include pattern="...(pattern here)"/>
    </api-classes>